# Html required attribute not firing with html select tag

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following  which has input fields and a select tag. the required attribute works well with my type="number" however with my select tag the required attribute is not working?

```html
<select class="js-select2-custom custom-select myClass" name="Description" size="1" id="@("txtDescription"+i)" @required
    data-hs-select2-options='{ "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity","placeholder": "Load" }'>
    <option label="empty"></option>
    <option value="Boxes" selected>Boxes</option>
    <option value="Envelop">Envelop</option>
    <option value="Pallet">Pallet</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You don't have a `required` attribute; you have a `@required` attribute, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the @required to required.

Basically remove the @ since required is part of a normal html element and the @ is causing the function to not be called

Your code would then look like this:

```
<select class="js-select2-custom custom-select myClass" name="Description" size="1" id="@("txtDescription"+i)" required
    data-hs-select2-options='{ "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity","placeholder": "Load" }'>
    <option label="empty"></option>
    <option value="Boxes" selected>Boxes</option>
    <option value="Envelop">Envelop</option>
    <option value="Pallet">Pallet</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `@required` attribute. That's something different then `required`.

```html
<select class="js-select2-custom custom-select myClass" name="Description" size="1" id="@("txtDescription"+i)" @required
    data-hs-select2-options='{ "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity","placeholder": "Load" }'>
    <option label="empty"></option>
    <option value="Boxes" selected>Boxes</option>
    <option value="Envelop">Envelop</option>
    <option value="Pallet">Pallet</option>
</select>
```